# SQL error code 1064 with creating Laravel foreign keys

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a table bankaccounts. In there I have a column 'user_id' that refers to the id of in the user table.

Now I want to add a foreign key to that column, but then I get this error.

> >
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) def' at line 1 (SQL: create table `bankaccounts` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `user_id` int unsigned not null, `accountnumber` varchar(191) not null, `bank` varchar(191) not null, `user_name` varchar(191) unsigned not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

I've already tried it with just the minimum change. Only add a foreign key on the user_id column.

I have the standard Laravel users migration and this is the bankaccounts migration.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('bankaccounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('accountnumber')->unique();
        $table->string('bank');
        $table->string('user_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('bankaccounts', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_name')->references('name')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, because I see tutorials online that also try it with the id from the users table, and they succeed.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a "unsigned" varchar.

You have

```
user_name varchar(191) unsigned not null
```

change it to

```
user_name varchar(191) not null
```

Comment: In the laravel migration, this is caused by `$table->string('user_name')->unsigned();`

Comment: Technically, because this is Laravel, OP needs to change `$table->string('user_name')->unsigned();` to `$table->string('user_name');`.

Comment: I edited my post. Even without the name, it still won't work. Now I'm getting this error:  General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `bankaccounts` add constraint `bankaccounts_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: @idontunderstandarrays That's a different problem and should be asked in a different question.

Comment: @EdCottrell Okay well, I changed it to your suggestion, removed the foreign key for the user_id and I'm also getting that same error.

Comment: You shouldn't remove the FK_, the FK is a link to your user's table and shouldn't be touched. Post your error in a new question and we'll help you out.